# Manipulating $C=\frac{C_a-C_b}{a-b}+\frac{aC_b-bC_a}{(a-b)m}$ into $C=\frac{1}{m}\Bigl(\frac{m-b}{a-b}C_a+\frac{a-m}{a-b}C_b\Bigr)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need to know the step to get this:

$$C=\frac{1}{m}\Bigl(\frac{m-b}{a-b}C_a+\frac{a-m}{a-b}C_b\Bigr)$$

from:

$$C=\frac{C_a-C_b}{a-b}+\frac{aC_b-bC_a}{(a-b)m}$$

Thank you!

Comment: Multiply both numerator an denominator of the first term by $m$, then group together terms with $C_a$

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: I've tried to multiply by m and divide by 1/m but there's something wrong and I don't understand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$C=\frac{C_a-C_b}{a-b}+\frac{aC_b-bC_a}{(a-b)m}$$
Multiply numerator and denominator in first term by $m$

$$C=\frac{C_a m-C_b m}{(a-b)m}+\frac{aC_b-bC_a}{(a-b)m}$$
Give $1/m$ as factor
$$C=\frac 1m\left(\frac{C_a m-C_b m}{a-b}+\frac{aC_b-bC_a}{a-b}\right)$$
Group terms with $C_a$ and separately $C_b$
$$C=\frac 1m\left(\frac{C_am-bC_a}{a-b}+\frac{-C_bm+aC_b}{a-b}\right)$$

Comment: Wow I can't believe it, thank you!!!